# SSD partition as cache for torrent?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, cache, bittorrent

I download some data using P2P, and I have the same issue as other uTorrent users lately - the famous and feared "Disk Cache Overload 100%" message. It cripples my system into a no-go when there's a bigger download and the disk I/O is at 100% (thanks to uT again).

Recently, I got an SSD, and while it is all good and shiny, there are some downloads that simply can't fit on it.

It is a 120GB Samsung EVO 840, and it works like a wonder.

As my system with everything installed uses about 50-60GBs, I was thinking about chunking off 20GB as a separate partition, to act like a temp storage for torrents.

However, uTorrent won't use it as I'd like it - as a temp storage until a file is downloaded then move it to the storage drive (which is a perfectly fine SATA-III Toshiba drive).

My question is - is there any option, or software, that would enable me to store partial data on this partition, for torrents? It can even be a different torrent client, I wouldn't mind it, as long as it is not a memory hog like Vuze (which, while working fine without any overloads and low CPU usage, eats up memory like an American eats cheeseburger).

Comment: And which download manager should I try? Please be specific, there are at least a hundred DM's out in the wild, some with torrent support, some without. Also if you noticed, my question contains quite specific feature requests, so saying that I should try a "download manager" is not helpful at all.

Comment: What's your mainboard? If it supports SSD cache then things would be much simpler. Otherwise you need some other solutions

Comment: My laptop is an HP 8530w, no built-in SSD cache support. And I wouldn't want my 120GB SSD as pure cache either.